# How to get all rows that contain many elements from another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a DB structure like the image below.  In this case I am trying to determine how I can get all the related Panels when a user selects a Panel or Class.  The key is the DAT_TestedDrugs, the related Panel must contain all the DAT_TestedDrugs for the selected Panel.

Example:  user selects Panel A
Panel A has TestedDrugs B and C

Panel X & Y also contain Tested Drugs B and C

Therefore ther result should be Panel A, Panel X, and Panel Y

I am using C# and Entity Framework for this application

[image]

Comment: can you please show some data of particular tables.? so it will be easy to understand your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the picture you seem to have something similar to the following classes that represent your data in c#:

```
public class Panel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<DrugClass> DrugClasses { get; set; }
}

public class DrugClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<TestedDrug> TestedDrugs { get; set; }
}

public class TestedDrug
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

where a Panel object has a list of DrugClass objects and each DrugClass object has a list of TestedDrug objects.

Then this method should give you the results that you need:

```
    public static List<Panel> GetPanelsWithSameTestedDrugs(List<Panel> panelList, Panel selectedPanel)
    {
        var testedDrugs = panelList
            .Where(panel => panel == selectedPanel)
            .SelectMany(panel => panel.Drugs)
            .SelectMany(drugClass => drugClass.TestedDrugs)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(testedDrug => testedDrug.ID);

        var panels = panelList.Where(panel => panel.DrugClasses
                                    .SelectMany(drugClass => drugClass.TestedDrugs)
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .OrderBy(testedDrug => testedDrug.ID)
                                    .SequenceEqual(testedDrugs));

        return panels.ToList();
    }
```

where `paneList` is the list of panel that you are working on (probably the entire table but not necessary) and `selectedPanel` is the user selected panel.

This should return a list of panels for which each panel has the same tested drugs as the `selectedPanel`. The list includes `selectedPanel` too (it can be removed at will).

Refactor to suit purpose...

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship *Panel -> TestedDrug* it's a little bit complex because it's ***Panel*** have many DrugClasses who have many **TestedDrugs**.

The query below work like this:

1. Get all `TestedDrugs` from current `panel`
2. Get all `Panels` and select only the panels that have the same tested drugs ,`allTestedDrugs.All(..)`.

Query:

```
var panel = // take from db
var panels = // get all from db
var allTestedDrugs = panel.DrugClasses.SelectMany(dg => dg.TestedDrugs).ToList();
var samePanels = panels.Where(p => allTestedDrugs.All(
                    testedDrug => p.DrugClasses.SelectMany(dg => dg.TestedDrugs)
                                            .Any(td => testedDrug.Id == td.Id))
                );
```

Your entities in C# looks like below.

```
public class DomainObject {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Panel : DomainObject{
    public List<DrugClass> DrugClasses { get; set; }
}

public class DrugClass : DomainObject {
    public List<TestedDrug> TestedDrugs { get; set; }
    public List<Panel> Panels { get; set; }
}

public class TestedDrug : DomainObject {
    public List<DrugClass> DrugClasses { get; set; }
}
```